# Finding function which satisfies the following equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So i've gotten a question in my ode math class which goes like this:

Find function y(x) that satisfies the following:

1. Has second order derivative.
2. Satisfies the equation: $-2y'(x)=y(1/x)$.

After some time of trial and error and by some luck, i found that $y=\sqrt{-x}$ satisfies the following.
Now, what i did was trying to brute force different functions that fit the equation, i know its very non rigorous way and i wonder if there any possible smarter ways to find this function by using real math tools (btw - i tried to derivate / integral the original equation and stuck there...)

Comment: Differentiating the equation gives $2y''(x)=y'(1/x) x^{-2}$. Substitute for $y'$ into the original equation to find $-4x^2 y''(x)=y(x)$. Solve this to find  $y(x)=C_1 \sqrt{x} + C_2 \sqrt{x} \ln(\sqrt{x})$. Find $C_1$ in terms of $C_2$ by demanding this $y(x) $satisfies the original equation: $C_1=-C_2/2$. The answer has one integration constant, as we expect.

Comment: Amazing! can you explain why did u substituted y'(x) with y'(1/x) ? i mean why this is even possible?

Comment: No problem! It is not possible to substitute $y'(x)$ for $y'(1/x)$. More details: On differentiating we have $-2y''(x)=-y'(1/x)x^{-2}$. Then let $x \to 1/x$ to get $-2y''(1/x)=-x^2 y'(x)$. Now substitute $y'(x)$ into the original to find an equation in $1/x$. Again let $x \to 1/x$ to get $-4x^2y''(x)=y(x)$

Comment: Thank you so much!